# Delphi - How to save bitmap to BLOB field in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, delphi, bitmap, blob, firemonkey

I am trying to add an array of TBitmap images to different records of a ClientDataSet (in a ftBlob field) and then save those records to a SQLite database. The BLOB field (DocImage) is a required field in the database.

However, my code does not seem to save the bitmaps to the blob field in the ClientDataSet at all... So when I call `BdmMain.cdsTrxDoc.ApplyUpdates(0)`, I get the error: "Field 'DocImage' must have a value."

I have checked the size of my BlobStream (BlobStream.Size) before and after calling `FTrxPhotoValue[i].SaveToStream(BlobStream)` and it does increase in size, but BlobField's data size remains 0.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
FTrxIDValue: Integer;
FTrxDocIDValue: array of Integer;
FTrxPhotoValue: array of TBitmap;
// ...
for i := 0 to Length(FTrxPhotoValue) do
begin
  BdmMain.cdsTrxDoc.Insert;
  BdmMain.cdsTrxDoc['TrxID'] := FTrxIDValue;
  BdmMain.cdsTrxDoc['DocID'] := FTrxDocIDValue[i];
  BlobField := BdmMain.cdsTrxDoc.FieldByName('DocImage');
  BlobStream := BdmMain.cdsTrxDoc.CreateBlobStream(BlobField, bmWrite);
  FTrxPhotoValue[i].SaveToStream(BlobStream);
end;
// ...
BdmMain.cdsTrxDoc.ApplyUpdates(0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `Free` the stream after the call to `SaveToStream`. The stream will update the underlying field only during `Destroy`.

Comment: I added BlobStream.Free after the call to SaveToStream but now I get an Access violation error...

Comment: Can you show the complete code and mark the line with the access violation?

Comment: Iterate `for i := 0 to Length(FTrxPhotoValue)-1 do`.