# Images don't get stored in table after resize

Tags: image, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I want to resize images stored in a database, but after the resize they don't store (as shown by other program accessing them).

This is the code:

```
procedure ScaleImages(ATableName,APicFieldName,ATypeFieldName: String);
const
   cMaxPicDim    = 512;
   cCompressQual = 70;
var
   lJPGImage  : TJpegImage;
   lBMPImage  : TBitmap;
   lBlobStream: TStream;
   lPhotoField: TBlobField;
   lTypeField : TField;
begin
   with QueryMiscUpdate do  // TFDQuery connected to TFDConnection to FireBird database
   begin
      Close;
      UpdateOptions.RequestLive := true;
      SQL.Text := 'select * from ' + ATableName;
      Open;
      lPhotoField := TBlobField(FieldByname(APicFieldName));
      lTypeField  := FieldByName(ATypeFieldName);
      while not eof do
      begin
         if not lPhotoField.IsNull then
         begin
            case lTypeField.asInteger of
               JPGCLASSTYPE: begin
                                lJPGImage := TJpegImage.Create;
                                Edit;
                                lBlobStream := CreateBlobStream(lPhotoField, bmReadWrite);
                                try
                                   try
                                      lJPGImage.LoadFromStream(lBlobStream);  // Width=3872, Height=2592
                                      ResizeJPGImageWithoutAlpha(lJPGImage, cMaxPicDim, cCompressQual); // lJPGImage.Width=512, Height=342
                                      // lBlobStream.Position := 0; Makes no difference
                                      lJPGImage.SaveToStream(lBlobStream);
                                   except
                                      on E:Exception do ShowMessage(E.Message); // debugging
                                   end;
                                finally
                                   lBlobStream.Free;  // *Before* the post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46099989/512728
                                   Post;
                                   lJPGImage.Free;
                                end;
                             end;
               // other formats...              
            end; // case
         end; // if not lPhotoField.IsNull
         Next;
      end; // while not eof
      Close;
   end;
end; // ScaleImages
```

Even if I split this into separate `TStream`s for reading/writing it does not work:

```
begin
   lJPGImage := TJpegImage.Create;
   lLoadStream := CreateBlobStream(lPhotoField, bmRead);
   try
      try
         lJPGImage.LoadFromStream(lLoadStream);
         ResizeJPGImageWithoutAlpha(lJPGImage, cMaxPicDim, cCompressQual);
         Edit;
         lSaveStream := CreateBlobStream(lPhotoField, bmWrite);
         lJPGImage.SaveToStream(lSaveStream);
      except
         on E:Exception do ShowMessage(E.Message); // debugging
      end;
   finally
      lLoadStream.Free;
      lSaveStream.Free;
      Post;
      lJPGImage.Free;
   end;
end;
```

FWIW, here's the resize code (old, working elsewhere):

```
procedure ResizeJPGImageWithoutAlpha(var AJPGImage: TJPegImage; AMaxDimension, ACompressionQuality: Integer);
var
   lBitmap   : TBitmap;
   lFactor   : Real;
   lNewWidth,
   lNewHeight: Integer;
begin
   if (AJPGImage.Width <= 128) and (AJPGImage.Height <= 128) then Exit;

   if AJPGImage.Width > AJPGImage.Height then
      if AJPGImage.Width > AMaxDimension then
         lFactor := AJPGImage.Width
      else
         lFactor := 0
   else
      if AJPGImage.Height > AMaxDimension then
         lFactor := AJPGImage.Height
      else
         lFactor := 0;
   if lFactor <> 0 then
   begin
      lFactor    := lFactor / AMaxDimension;
      lNewWidth  := Trunc(AJPGImage.Width  / lFactor);
      lNewHeight := Trunc(AJPGImage.Height / lFactor);
      lBitmap    := TBitmap.Create;
      try
         lBitmap.Width := lNewWidth;
         lBitmap.Height:= lNewHeight;
         lBitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw(lBitmap.Canvas.Cliprect, AJPGImage);
         // Convert back to JPEG
         AJPGImage.Assign(lBitmap);
      finally
         lBitmap.free;
      end;
   end
   else
      AJPGImage.DIBNeeded;
      // Decompress the jpeg image into a bitmap.
      // DIBNeeded is used when the jpeg image needs a bitmap representation of its image.
      // Compress will not work without that (width/height become 0). The resize code already caused a bitmap.
   AJPGImage.CompressionQuality := ACompressionQuality;
   AJPGImage.Compress;
end;
```

Possibly relevant `TFDConnection.FetchOptions` and `TFDConnection.UpdateOptions` are default:

[image] [image]

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE <OWNER>TT_EMP_PHOTO 
(
  TT_EMP_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  TT_PHOTO BLOB SUB_TYPE 0 SEGMENT SIZE 80,
  TT_PHOTO_TYPE INTEGER,
  TT_INFO BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT SEGMENT SIZE 80,
  TT_TAG INTEGER,
  TT_TAGTYPE INTEGER,
  TT_TAGDATE TIMESTAMP
);
```

Table contains correct data (other programs<sup>*</sup> can read/write the images).

There are already a lot of questions about saving images on SO, but going through them I do not see: *What am I overlooking*?

Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1, Win32 app, Firebird 2.5.3.26778

<sup>* They use `TClientDataSets` and picture components, so the code does not directly compare.</sup>

---

FDMonitor output for the Post statement:

```
>> TFDCustomCommand.Prepare [Command="select * from tt_emp_photo"]
     . CreateCommand [ConnectionDef=""]
     . Adapter DataModuleData.QueryMiscUpdate registered with client
     . Preprocessed [CMD="select * from tt_emp_photo", FROM="tt_emp_photo", VP=0, VPE=0, OBP=0, CK=1]
<< TFDCustomCommand.Prepare [Command="select * from tt_emp_photo"]
>> Lock [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
    >> StartTransaction [ConnectionDef=""]
         . isc_start_multiple [count=1, params="write,read_committed,rec_version,wait"]
    << StartTransaction [ConnectionDef=""]
     . CreateCommand [ConnectionDef=""]
     . Adapter tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Lock: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90) registered with client
     . Preprocessed [CMD="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG, A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = ? FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK", FROM="TT_EMP_PHOTO", VP=0, VPE=0, OBP=0, CK=1]
    >> ProcessRequest [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
        >> tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Lock: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90).Prepare [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG, A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
             . Preprocessed [CMD="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG, A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = ? FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK", FROM="TT_EMP_PHOTO", VP=0, VPE=0, OBP=0, CK=1]
             . isc_dsql_allocate_statement [db_handle=$00000021]
             . isc_dsql_prepare [tra_handle=$00000059, stmt_handle=$0000005A, sql="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = ? FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK", dialect=3]
             . isc_dsql_sql_info [stmt_handle=$0000005A, info=21]
             . isc_dsql_describe [stmt_handle=$0000005A, dialect=3]
             . isc_dsql_describe_bind [stmt_handle=$0000005A, dialect=3]
        << Prepare [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
        >> Open [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
            >> DataModuleDatabase.FDConnectionTimeTell.Sent
                 . Var [N=0, Name="OLD_TT_EMP_ID", Type=SQL_LONG, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=4, Data(0)=1]
            << Sent
             . isc_dsql_execute2 [tra_handle=$00000059, stmt_handle=$0000005A, dialect=3]
        << tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Lock: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90).Open [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
        >> Define(TFDDatSTable) [ATable="Table", Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
             . Col add [Index=1, SrcName="TT_EMP_ID", SrcType=Int32, SrcSize=0, SrcPrec=0, SrcScale=0, Type=Int32, Size=0, Prec=0, Scale=0, OrigTabName="TT_EMP_PHOTO", OrigColName="TT_EMP_ID"]
             . Col add [Index=2, SrcName="TT_PHOTO", SrcType=Blob, SrcSize=0, SrcPrec=0, SrcScale=0, Type=Blob, Size=0, Prec=0, Scale=0, OrigTabName="TT_EMP_PHOTO", OrigColName="TT_PHOTO"]
             . Col add [Index=3, SrcName="TT_PHOTO_TYPE", SrcType=Int32, SrcSize=0, SrcPrec=0, SrcScale=0, Type=Int32, Size=0, Prec=0, Scale=0, OrigTabName="TT_EMP_PHOTO", OrigColName="TT_PHOTO_TYPE"]
             . Col add [Index=4, SrcName="TT_INFO", SrcType=Memo, SrcSize=0, SrcPrec=0, SrcScale=0, Type=Memo, Size=0, Prec=0, Scale=0, OrigTabName="TT_EMP_PHOTO", OrigColName="TT_INFO"]
             . Col add [Index=5, SrcName="TT_TAG", SrcType=Int32, SrcSize=0, SrcPrec=0, SrcScale=0, Type=Int32, Size=0, Prec=0, Scale=0, OrigTabName="TT_EMP_PHOTO", OrigColName="TT_TAG"]
             . Col add [Index=6, SrcName="TT_TAGTYPE", SrcType=Int32, SrcSize=0, SrcPrec=0, SrcScale=0, Type=Int32, Size=0, Prec=0, Scale=0, OrigTabName="TT_EMP_PHOTO", OrigColName="TT_TAGTYPE"]
             . Col add [Index=7, SrcName="TT_TAGDATE", SrcType=DateTimeStamp, SrcSize=0, SrcPrec=0, SrcScale=0, Type=DateTime, Size=0, Prec=0, Scale=0, OrigTabName="TT_EMP_PHOTO", OrigColName="TT_TAGDATE"]
        << Define(TFDDatSTable) [ATable="tt_emp_photo", Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
        >> Fetch [ATable="tt_emp_photo", Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
             . isc_dsql_fetch [stmt_handle=$0000005A, dialect=3]
            >> DataModuleDatabase.FDConnectionTimeTell.Fetched
                 . Var [N=0, Type=SQL_LONG, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=4, Data=1]
                 . Var [N=1, Type=SQL_BLOB, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=8, Data=<BLOB> (179,3)]
                 . Var [N=2, Type=SQL_LONG, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=4, Data=1]
                 . Var [N=3, Type=SQL_BLOB, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=8, Data=<BLOB> (179,1)]
                 . Var [N=4, Type=SQL_LONG, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=4, Data=NULL]
                 . Var [N=5, Type=SQL_LONG, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=4, Data=NULL]
                 . Var [N=6, Type=SQL_TIMESTAMP, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=8, Data=NULL]
            << Fetched
             . isc_open_blob2 [db_handle=$00000021, tra_handle=$00000059, blob_id.high=179, blob_id.low=3]
             . isc_blob_info [blob_handle=$0000005B, items="num_segments;max_segment;total_length;type"]
             . isc_get_segment [blob_handle=$0000005B]
             [.. repeats 30+ times ..]
             . isc_close_blob [blob_handle=$0000005B]
             . isc_open_blob2 [db_handle=$00000021, tra_handle=$00000059, blob_id.high=179, blob_id.low=1]
             . isc_blob_info [blob_handle=$0000005C, items="num_segments;max_segment;total_length;type"]
             . isc_get_segment [blob_handle=$0000005C]
             . isc_close_blob [blob_handle=$0000005C]
        << tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Lock: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90).Fetch [ATable="tt_emp_photo", Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK", RowsAffected=1]
         . Eof reached [ATable="tt_emp_photo", Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
        >> Close [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
             . isc_dsql_free_statement [stmt_handle=$0000005A, option="DSQL_close"]
        << DataModuleDatabase.FDConnectionTimeTell.Close [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
        >> tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Lock: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90).Open [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
        << Open [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
    << ProcessRequest [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
<< Lock [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
>> Unprepare [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
     . isc_dsql_free_statement [stmt_handle=$0000005A, option="DSQL_drop"]
<< Unprepare [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
 . Destroy [Command="SELECT A.TT_EMP_ID, A.TT_PHOTO, A.TT_PHOTO_TYPE, A.TT_INFO, A.TT_TAG,    A.TT_TAGTYPE, A.TT_TAGDATE FROM TT_EMP_PHOTO A WHERE A.TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID FOR UPDATE WITH LOCK"]
 . Adapter tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Lock: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90) unregistered with client
>> Update [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
     . CreateCommand [ConnectionDef=""]
     . Adapter tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Update: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90) registered with client
     . Preprocessed [CMD="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = ? WHERE TT_EMP_ID = ?", FROM="", VP=0, VPE=0, OBP=0, CK=7]
    >> ProcessRequest [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
        >> tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Update: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90).Prepare [Command="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = :NEW_TT_PHOTO WHERE TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID"]
             . Preprocessed [CMD="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = ? WHERE TT_EMP_ID = ?", FROM="", VP=0, VPE=0, OBP=0, CK=7]
             . isc_dsql_allocate_statement [db_handle=$00000021]
             . isc_dsql_prepare [tra_handle=$00000059, stmt_handle=$0000005D, sql="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = ? WHERE TT_EMP_ID = ?", dialect=3]
             . isc_dsql_sql_info [stmt_handle=$0000005D, info=21]
             . isc_dsql_describe_bind [stmt_handle=$0000005D, dialect=3]
             . isc_dsql_describe_bind [stmt_handle=$0000005D, dialect=3]
        << Prepare [Command="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = :NEW_TT_PHOTO WHERE TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID"]
        >> Execute [Command="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = :NEW_TT_PHOTO WHERE TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID", ATimes=0, AOffset=0]
             . isc_create_blob2 [db_handle=$00000021, tra_handle=$00000059]
             . isc_blob_info [blob_handle=$0000005E, items="num_segments;max_segment;total_length;type"]
             . isc_put_segment [blob_handle=$0000005E]
             . isc_put_segment [blob_handle=$0000005E]
             . isc_put_segment [blob_handle=$0000005E]
             . isc_put_segment [blob_handle=$0000005E]
             . isc_put_segment [blob_handle=$0000005E]
             . isc_put_segment [blob_handle=$0000005E]
             . isc_put_segment [blob_handle=$0000005E]
             . isc_put_segment [blob_handle=$0000005E]
             . isc_put_segment [blob_handle=$0000005E]
             . isc_close_blob [blob_handle=$0000005E]
            >> DataModuleDatabase.FDConnectionTimeTell.Sent
                 . Var [N=0, Name="NEW_TT_PHOTO", Type=SQL_BLOB, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=8, Data(0)=<BLOB> (0,3)]
                 . Var [N=1, Name="OLD_TT_EMP_ID", Type=SQL_LONG, Prec=0, Scale=0, Size=4, Data(0)=1]
            << Sent
             . isc_dsql_execute2 [tra_handle=$00000059, stmt_handle=$0000005D, dialect=3]
             . isc_dsql_sql_info [stmt_handle=$0000005D, info=23]
        << tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Update: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90).Execute [Command="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = :NEW_TT_PHOTO WHERE TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID", ATimes=1, AOffset=0, RowsAffected=1, RowsAffectedReal=True, ErrorAction=5]
        >> Open [Command="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = :NEW_TT_PHOTO WHERE TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID"]
        << Open [Command="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = :NEW_TT_PHOTO WHERE TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID"]
    << ProcessRequest [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
<< Update [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
>> Unprepare [Command="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = :NEW_TT_PHOTO WHERE TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID"]
     . isc_dsql_free_statement [stmt_handle=$0000005D, option="DSQL_drop"]
<< Unprepare [Command="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = :NEW_TT_PHOTO WHERE TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID"]
 . Destroy [Command="UPDATE TT_EMP_PHOTO SET TT_PHOTO = :NEW_TT_PHOTO WHERE TT_EMP_ID = :OLD_TT_EMP_ID"]
 . Adapter tt_emp_photo: TFDDAptTableAdapter($04542520).Update: TFDPhysIBCommand($04491A90) unregistered with client
>> UnLock [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
    >> DataModuleDatabase.FDConnectionTimeTell.Commit [ConnectionDef="", Retaining=False]
         . isc_commit_transaction [tra_handle=$00000059]
    << Commit [ConnectionDef="", Retaining=False]
<< UnLock [ARow.Table.Name="tt_emp_photo"]
```

Comment: Does the `Post` cause any database activity (is an update statement fired)?

Comment: @nil I'm tracing what's going on, but [this does not help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831043/tfdmoniflatfileclientlink-irregularly-does-not-trace-to-file)

Comment: Oh damn, that sounds like bad luck. I would say your code looks solid, therefore I was interested in what happens at DB component level. Maybe there is some other profiling option you can use, like SQL Server Profiler for MS SQL? Have you tried creating a separate `TMemoryStream` and then use `TBlobField.SaveToStream` and `TBlobField.LoadFromStream`? (I think that is what @A. Fornés is suggesting).

Comment: [This does not help either](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19559)

Comment: @nil Trace added to question...

Answer (score 1):

I would replace

```
lBlobStream := CreateBlobStream(lPhotoField, bmReadWrite);
```

with `lBlobStream: TMemoryStream` and then this:

```
lBlobStream.Clear; 
lPhotoField.SaveToStream(lBlobStream);
lBlobStream.Position := 0;
```

then

```
try
  lJPGImage.LoadFromStream(lBlobStream);
  ...
```

and at the beginning of the procedure:

```
  lBlobStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
```

and at the end

```
  lBlobStream.free;
```

I checked your code with Delphi XE7, Firebird 2.1 and it did not work, but this worked for me:

```
procedure TForm1.ScaleImages(ATableName,APicFieldName,ATypeFieldName: String);
const
   cMaxPicDim    = 512;
   cCompressQual = 70;
var
   lJPGImage  : TJpegImage;
   lBMPImage  : TBitmap;
   //lBlobStream: TStream;
   lBlobStream: TMemoryStream;
   lPhotoField: TBlobField;
   lTypeField : TField;
begin
   lBlobStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
   with QueryMiscUpdate do  // TFDQuery connected to TFDConnection to FireBird database
   begin
      Close;
      UpdateOptions.RequestLive := true;
      SQL.Text := 'select * from ' + ATableName;
      Open;
      lPhotoField := TBlobField(FieldByname(APicFieldName));
      lTypeField  := FieldByName(ATypeFieldName);
      while not eof do
      begin
       if not lPhotoField.IsNull then
         begin

            lJPGImage := TJpegImage.Create;
            Edit;
            lBlobStream.Clear;
            lPhotoField.SaveToStream(lBlobStream);
            lBlobStream.Position:= 0;
            //lBlobStream := CreateBlobStream(lPhotoField, bmReadWrite);
            try
               try
                  lJPGImage.LoadFromStream(lBlobStream);  // Width=3872, Height=2592
                  ResizeJPGImageWithoutAlpha(lJPGImage, cMaxPicDim, cCompressQual); // lJPGImage.Width=512, Height=342
                  // lBlobStream.Position := 0; Makes no difference
                  lBlobStream.Clear; //<-- If I remove this, it doesn't work
                  lJPGImage.SaveToStream(lBlobStream);
                  lBlobStream.Position:= 0;
                  lPhotoField.LoadFromStream(lBlobStream);
               except
                  on E:Exception do ShowMessage(E.Message); // debugging
               end;
            finally
               //lBlobStream.Free;  // *Before* the post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46099989/512728
               Post;
               lJPGImage.Free;
            end;

               // other formats...
            //end; // case
         end; // if not lPhotoField.IsNull
         Next;
      end; // while not eof
      Close;
   end;
 lBlobStream.Free;
end; // ScaleImages
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I'm not marking your answer as **the** correct one (yet) because I'm still curious if anyone finds a reason why it did not work. I use TStreams elsewhere in my code to do the same image shrinking, on TClientDataSets, and there it works...

Comment: Maybe the second   lBlobStream.Clear;  give you some clue about the problem. As I indicated in the code if I remove this, it doesn't work.