# TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink irregularly does not trace to file

Tags: delphi, monitoring, trace, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a `TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink` on a form, filename set to `d:\temp\monitor.txt`, tracing=true, `TFDConnection.Params.MonitorBy=mbFlatFile`. This sometimes works and sometimes does not trace anything. No file gets created.

Tested with Win7 32-bit app, with design time `TFDConnection` to either FireBird or Oracle. Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a really weird bug:

It turns out that the `TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink` remembers the filename when removed and placed back, then does not trace.

To reproduce:

Remove the `TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink`, optionally save the project, place a `TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink` on the form again, set tracing=true. It has magically remembered filename `d:\temp\monitor.txt` (where?), then either does not trace or traces to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\traceX.txt`.

**Only when you change the filename does it successfully trace again**.<sup>*</sup>

Similar weird things happen with `TFDMoniRemoteFileClientLink`, it very often does not create trace output for FDMonitor to pick up. I have not investigated the exact conditions under which this happens.

I found this in a test app after tracing the following issue, possibly related:<sup>**</sup>

A design time `TFDConnection` gets its parameters filled at run-time. I executed `TFDConnection.Params.Add('MonitorBy=mbFlatFile')` but the app did not trace. I verified that `MonitorByInitial=true` at run-time. `Params.Add('MonitorBy=mbRemote')` also failed.
A `TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink` and `TFDMoniRemoteClientLink` were placed on the datamodule at design time.

Reported in Embarcadero Quality Portal under issue [RSP-19554](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19554)

<sup>* Even if you change it to the same file name. If you do that at run-time you have to set `Tracing=false/true` around the FileName assignment.</sup>

<sup>** Mmm, not related. Reported as [RSP-19559](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19559)</sup>